# Dropbox proxy requests

Tags: dropbox-api

It's possible to do a server side .NET that authenticates to Dropbox and then on the browser side users connect to a website and can read files from that Dropbox account?

In other words the server acts as an authentication proxy for Dropbox requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to interact with their own Dropbox account, they will need to authorize your app in their browser, but after that you can use the Dropbox .NET SDK to make API calls to Dropbox from your server:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet

Comment: We need users to login to our system only and access one dropbox account only. In other words many users access the same dropbox account. That account is a company account with shared readonly documents. We don't want the users access the dropbox account, so the server only has the credentials to access that only dropbox account.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. This isn't the intended use of the Dropbox API, but it is possible. You can do this essentially the same way, just by using a single access token for that account, and making the calls from your server code.